# WebBrowser not displaying content

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm having a problem with WebBrowser control in WP7. Can anyone explain to me  why does example 1 works and example 2 doesn't?

### Example 1:

#### XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="grForWebBrowser">
    <phone:WebBrowser Name="wb"/>
</Grid>
```

#### CodeBehind

```
const string html = "<html><h2>TEST</h2></html >";
wb.NavigateToString(html);
```

### Example 2:

#### XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spForWebBrowser"/>
```

#### CodeBehind

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
const string html = "<html><h2>TEST</h2></html>";
wb.NavigateToString(html);
spForWebBrowser.Children.Add(wb);
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Ok, one update. I found out that I can't put WebBrowser in StackPanel, and it is working great in Grid. So my question now is how to make it work inside of StackPanel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does work.  You just haven't set the width and height properties of the webBroswer so it is defaulting to 0 x 0

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
string html = "<html><h2>TEST</h2></html>";
wb.NavigateToString(html);
wb.Height = 150.0;
wb.Width=440.0;
spForWebBrowser.Children.Add(wb);
// or 
grForWebBrowser.Children.Add(wb);
```

You could also control the size of the WebBrowser using Margins, but for the sake of explanation I explicitly set it's dimensions.

Comment: OMG,you are right. I was lost for some time over this. Thank you.